# How to do Contact Number Restriction using TextBox Length?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

You see contact numbers in my country are focused to 7 or 11 digits only. But I cant seem to get my how is the Len not working.

This is my code:

```
    If Len(TextBox5.Text) <> 11 Or Len(TextBox5.Text) <> 7 Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Contact Number")
    Else
        MsgBox("Contact Number Accepted")
    End If
```

Comment: Make use of `Using` statements which implements `IDisposable`. You can have as many nested data readers within them as you like. Just remember to name them distinctly.

Comment: can you show me an example using my code?

Comment: @DanielShillcock im not familliar with that to be honest

Comment: Your inconsistent casing makes me feel sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fine to have nested data readers, however I recommend you make use of `Using` statements which will dispose of your datareaders for you (or anything else that implements `IDisposable`).

Please see the general premise below.

```
 Using firstDataReader As New MySqlDataReader()
     firstDataReader.ExecuteReader("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE")
     If (firstDataReader.Read) Then
         using secondDataReader as New MySqlDataReader()
             secondDataReader.ExecuterReader("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ANOTHER_TABLE")
             If (secondDataReader.Read) Then
                 'Do Stuff
             End If 
         End Using
     End If
End Using
```

As you can see, there is no need to `Dispose()` objects yourself. .NET CLR will dispose of them when exiting `Using` statement.

Comment: Last time I checked MySql doesn't allow two open datareaders on the same connection.